# Throw with Error Message C++

Tags: c++, exception

What I have tried:

```
class MyException : public std::runtime_error {};

throw MyException("Sorry out of bounds, should be between 0 and "+limit);
```

I am not sure how I can implement such a feature.

Comment: Spending time in the *thousands* of "C++ Custom Exception Objects" hits from Google will likely pay off more than coming here and being abused for not asking an actual question. The [recommended book list for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?rq=1) has some outstanding sections on stuff like this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:  how to have your exception accept a string parameter, and how to create a string from runtime information.

```
class MyException : public std::runtime_error 
{
    MyExcetion(const std::string& message) // pass by const reference, to avoid unnecessary copying
    :  std::runtime_error(message)
    {}          
};
```

Then you have different ways to construct the string argument:

1. [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is most convenient, but is a C++11 function.

   ```
   throw MyException(std::string("Out of bounds, should be between 0 and ") 
                     + std::to_string(limit));
   ```
2. Or use [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) (function name is a link).

   ```
   throw MyException(std::string("Out of bounds, should be between 0 and ")
                     + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(limit));
   ```
3. You could also create a C-string buffer and use [a printf style command](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). `std::snprintf` would be preferred, but is also C++11.

   ```
   char buffer[24];
   int retval = std::sprintf(buffer, "%d", limit);  // not preferred
   // could check that retval is positive
   throw MyException(std::string("Out of bounds, should be between 0 and ")
                      + buffer);
   ```

Comment: John Smith, thank you.  I edited and corrected for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a constructor function for MyException which accepts a string and then sends it to std::runtime_error's constructor.  Something like this:

```
class MyException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    MyException(std::string str) : std::runtime_error(str)
    {
    }
};
```